# How to decrease size of a Photoshop rendered HTML email signature?

Tags: html, css, photoshop

i have been working on an HTML email signature that i designed in Photoshop and sliced it and exported HTML out of it.

But now i want the whole size down by 50% lets say maybe through CSS? i tried CSS on all selectors where possible but it does not seem to have any effect. Here is the HTML code.

Please if some one knows a trick so that i won't be resizing in Photoshop and again slicing it.

```
<html><head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <style media="screen" type="text/css">
         td {line-height:0; font-size:0.0cm }
         img { display: block; float: left; padding: 0; align: absbottom; align: texttop; }
  </style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (dino-01.png) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="488" height="189" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td rowspan="4">
            <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/etxa5h7fdgvvuwp/dino-01_01.png?dl=0" width="192" height="189" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/7nu3zn0ghisccat/dino-01_02.png?dl=0" width="296" height="80" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/kixqyw291n0vod0/dino-01_03.png?dl=0" width="72" height="109" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <a href="db@itfs.ly"><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/4i9lelm15oqj28h/dino-01_04.png?dl=0" width="224" height="23" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="tel:021-722-3332 "><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/n38tsk7mnwgwl4s/dino-01_05.png?dl=0" width="224" height="21" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="www.itfs.ly"><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/ru4uplnmmxbsw90/dino-01_06.png?dl=0" width="224" height="65" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->


</body></html>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the width and height attributes of the img tags?

Comment: Besides this your e-mail is by having so many external urls more likely to be considered as spam. I would think of just using only one picture or plain html for your signature. In many e-mail accounts/applications images from external sources are not loaded by default.

Comment: @TimNikischin i tried reducing height and width using CSS but it gave weird img size maybe its not responsive?

Comment: Styling in an e-mail is really limited.  You're going to want to make everything explicit in size, and inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

50% smaller file size you mean?

If so you could save the file as a jpg which is a much smaller file then a png.
Also when you save a file on photoshop you can go to file>export>save for web and compare different file types/sizes/quality. for something like a signature I would make a jpeg file with the quality set to medium and optimized for web checked.

or.. if you are talking about resizing it as far the picture dimensions. other than using photoshop there are services like https://onlinejpgtools.com/resize-jpg where you can drag and drop and image and resize it.

orrr... with css if you want to downsize the whole table you can add the style
     table {transform:scale(0.5);}

Comment: No, JPEG is not necessarily smaller than PNG.  JPEG should be used for photos.  For computer-rendered stuff where there are likely to be large swaths of the same color, use PNG.  Not only will the PNG typically be much smaller in size, but it's lossless so it will look better too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it seems like when I apply to transform:scale(0.5) it ruins everything but it does downsize it. Nevermind i had to do some modification in my export settings i will post them here once done.